# Resizing Fullscreen World Map D3JS

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, mapping, fullscreen

I'm trying to make a fullscreen world map with D3JS to put some markers on it. The thing is that I can't find a way to center it and make it responsive regarding the screen (even on a smartphone). How can I achieve this? Thanks!

```js
// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .translate([width / 2.15, height / 1.26])

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data) {

  // Draw the map
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#DEB887")
    .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)
    )
    .style("stroke", "#13788a")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #005f73;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="900"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: instead of a width and a height use a viewBox attribute for the svg element

Answer (score 1):

Take the window size using [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) and use the convenience function [`projection.fitSize`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitSize) to make the projection span the entire available field.

If you want to make the changes respond to window resizes, just redraw the map whenever the window size changes, using the `resize` event listener.

```js
// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight;

svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data) {

  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .fitSize([width, height], data);

  // Draw the map
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#DEB887")
    .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)
    )
    .style("stroke", "#13788a")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #005f73;
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
```